# PopUp Dialogs not working after form submit in jquery mobile

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, forms, jquery-mobile

I'm doing a simple form submit.On the form submit i have the form action="Facility.aspx".on Facility.aspx i'm using dialog popups.after the form submit those dialogs are not working but they are working before submitting the form.

**First Form HTML:**

```
<html> 
    <head> 
    <title>Facility</title> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.0/jquery.mobile-1.3.0.min.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.0/jquery.mobile-1.3.0.min.js"></script>
</head> 
<body> 

<div data-role="page" id="arealistpage">

  <div data-role="header" data-theme="b">
      <a href="Facility.aspx" class='ui-btn-left ui-btn-back' data-icon='arrow-l' rel="external">Back</a>
   </div><!-- /header -->

    <div data-role="content">  
  <form id="form1" method="post">
    <div id="AreaNoDiv" data-role="fieldcontain" class="field">
        <label for="Facility">Facility*</label>     
        <input id="Facility" name="shipNo_r" type="text" required/>
    </div>

     <div id="desDiv" data-role="fieldcontain" class="field">

        <label for="des" id="Label1" name="fnameLabel">Description*</label>     
        <input id="des" name="fname_r" type="text" required/>

    </div>
     <div id="submitDiv" data-role="fieldcontain" style="width: 30%">    
     <button class="btnLogin" data-theme="b" type="submit" id='mysubmit'>submit</button>
    </div>

    </form>

    </div><!-- /content -->

    <div data-role="footer" data-theme="b" data-position="fixed">

            <div data-role="navbar">
            <ul>

               <li><a href="" data-role="tab" data-icon="arrow-u" class="returnTopAction">Top</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div><!-- /page -->
<script src="Submitscript.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**Script:**

```
$('#arealistpage').live('pageshow',function(event){
var serviceURL = 'service1.asmx/SubmitList';
    $('#mysubmit').bind('click', function(e){
            $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: serviceURL,
            data: '{"name":"' + name + '"}',
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: successFunc,
            error: errorFunc
        });
    });

    function successFunc(data, status) {

        // parse it as object
       // var outStr = JSON.parse(data.d);
       // alert(outStr);
    }

    function errorFunc() {
        alert('error');
    }
});
```

**My Second From where the dialogs are not working after form submit.**

```
<html> 
    <head> 
    <title>Facility</title> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.0/jquery.mobile-1.3.0.min.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.0/jquery.mobile-1.3.0.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript">
     $('#arealistpage').live('pageshow', function (event) {
         $('div[id="primaryList"] ul[data-role="listview"] a').bind("click", function () {
             var facilityid = $(this).data("facilityid");
             sessionStorage.facilityid = facilityid;
            });
     });
</script>

</head> 
<body> 

<div data-role="page" id="arealistpage">

  <div data-role="header" data-theme="b">
        <h1><a name="top"></a>Facility</h1>
       <a href="../MenuePages/Dictionaries.aspx" class='ui-btn-left ui-btn-back' data-icon='arrow-l' rel="external">Back</a>
   <a href="AddFacility.aspx" data-role="button" data-icon="plus" data-theme="d" style="float:left;"  rel="external" data-transition="slide" data-ajax="false">Add</a>
    </div><!-- /header -->

    <div data-role="content">  
     <div id="primaryList">
    <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" data-theme="c"  data-filter="true" id="areaList" data-split-icon="gear" data-split-theme="d">

    </ul>

        </div>
    </div><!-- /content -->

    <div data-role="footer" data-theme="b" data-position="fixed">

            <div data-role="navbar">
            <ul>

               <li><a href="" data-role="tab" data-icon="arrow-u" class="returnTopAction">Top</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
   <script src="FacilityScript.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

</div><!-- /page -->
  <div data-role="page" id="dialog">
  <div data-role="header" data-theme="b">
    <h1>Options</h1>
  </div>   
 <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="false"
                data-theme="c">
               <li data-icon="false"><a href="UpdateFacility.aspx"  data-ajax="false">Edit</a></li>

              <li data-icon="false"><a href="#divMsg" data-rel="dialog" data-transition="pop">Delete</a></li>

            </ul>   
</div> 
<div data-role="page" id="divMsg">
  <div data-role="header" data-theme="b">
    <h1>Confirmation</h1>
  </div>   

  <div data-role="content">  
  <a href="Facility.aspx" onclick="DeleteFacility(); return true" data-role="button"  data-ajax="false">Delete Record?</a>
  </div>
   <script src="FacilityScript.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**Facility.js**

```
$('#arealistpage').live('pageshow', function (event) {
    $.mobile.showPageLoadingMsg();
    var serviceURL = '../ServiceScripts/FacilityWebService.asmx/GetFacilityList';

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: serviceURL,
        data: param = "",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: successFunc,
        error: errorFunc
    });

    function successFunc(data, status) {

        // parse it as object
        var lankanListArray = JSON.parse(data.d);

        // creating html string
        var listString = ""; //'<ul data-role="listview" id="areaList">';
        var htmlList = "";

        // running a loop
        items = [];
        $.each(lankanListArray, function (index, value) {
            items.push('<li><a href="#dialog" data-rel="dialog" data-transition="pop" data-facilityid=' + this.FacilityID + '><p>Facility: ' + this.FacilityN + '  |&nbsp;&nbsp;Description: ' + this.FacilityDescription + '</p></a><a class="deleteMe"></a></li>');

        });

        $('#areaList').empty();
        $('#areaList').append(items.join(''));
        $('#areaList').listview('refresh');
        $.mobile.hidePageLoadingMsg();

    }

    function errorFunc() {
        alert('error');
    }
});

$('#arealistpage').live('pageshow', function (event) {

    $.mobile.showPageLoadingMsg();
    var serviceURL = '../ServiceScripts/FacilityWebService.asmx/InsertFacility';

    $('#btnAdd').bind('click', function (e) {
        var Facility = $("#Facility").val();
        var Description = $("#des").val();
        // e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: serviceURL,
            data: '{"Facility":"' + Facility + '","FacilityDescription":"' + Description + '"}',
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: successFunc,
            error: errorFunc
        });
    });
    function successFunc(data, status) {
        var lankanListArray = JSON.parse(data.d);

    }

    function errorFunc() {
        alert("Form Submit Error");

    }
});
```

Comment: I'll check and getback to you today

Comment: what do you have in the script `FacilityScript.js`?

Comment: I'm doing a form submission and a form load on Facility.js.see the update

Comment: I checked the page response after form submit.The response contains only the first page("arealistpage"). The other two data-role pages where i used to get popup dialogs are not present in the response. so i guess the page is partially loadded

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 <a href="AddFacility.aspx" data-role="button" data-icon="plus" data-theme="d" style="float:left;"  rel="external" data-transition="slide" data-ajax="false">Add</a>
```

I solved the issue by removing rel="external" and data-ajax="false" tags. in the above line of code from my web form

Answer (score 0):

As a thumb rule in jQuery Mobile you need to have unique ID for each of yoru page. I see that you have used same ID for both your pages. Change the ID of your page and change the relevant ID in the JS file.

It should work fine. All looks ok to me. check and update me.

**update**

You can navigate to your new page using `$.mobile.changePage('yourpage.html');`

so you should call above method in your success function after form submit.

Comment: I change the page IDs still not working.One more thing.After the form submit -> navigate to second page.Once i refresh the second page everything is working fine.

Comment: I tried with both $.mobile.changePage("Facility.aspx"); and <form action="Facility.aspx" still the same issue.

Comment: did you place ` $.mobile.changePage("Facility.aspx");` inside `successFunc` of the page which handles POST request?

Comment: yes.i think even with simple form submit this happens.i added a new question.can u please just see the two simple web forms. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15265773/webform-not-behaving-properly-after-form-submission

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. I was adding a script outside the data-role="page" element in the html page for specific page. So my popup was not working when page was changed because JQM only renders the content inside the data-role="page" container (or inside body tag is page is not available in the html document). So I added my code in pageinit in my starting page of the application (i.e. index.html). This is how i did

```
$( document ).delegate("#addseat-page", "pageinit", function() {
  $("#vipPopup").popup(); //vip popup
  $("#popup-reservedseat").popup(); // reserved seat popup
});
```

It worked for me.

Reference : http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.1/docs/pages/page-scripting.html

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. The issue is about the ID of the popup.
My aproach was generate a random suffix and concatenate de string ID with this suffix.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).