# jQuery Mobile with ASP.NET and SQL Server

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, jquery-mobile

Hopefully this question is not to broad or inappropriate for Stack Overflow.  I use VS2013 to develop an asp.net website based upon SQL Server.  I want to make a jquery mobile app that needs much of the DB content and would like to reuse my existing EF-linq-VB code.   I've looked at somewhat similar questions here, but not found a good way to get started.  I have ample books for the jquery mobile UI and often use regular jQuery in my web pages.  It's not clear to me if I should start with an aspx page or an html page.  If aspx then does this cause problems for jquery mobile?  If html, then how to call VB code behind and move data back to the html page?  Is there an good tutorial or example that deals with this?  Thanks.

Comment: Hi, I understand and respect the rules - as I noted, I wasn't sure if my question was too broad.  However, have you considered having some kind of section in Stack Overflow just for this type of question?  As, I'm sure you noticed, I got some very helpful advice in a matter of minutes - advice that saves me a lot of time with my project.  Such a special section could be ignored by contributors who don't want to deal with this type of question.  Perhaps there are cost issues which make this impractical - just a thought. Many thanks for the great service you do provide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jquery mobile is Bulid on Javascript Base and It is Client Script , ASP.NET is on ServerSide  .

so You can Choice html or aspx to Use jquery mobile. if you want exchange data. like Insert ,

Update, Delete. You can Use Json on ASP.NET in WebService or WebApi

ref

http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.2.0/docs/forms/forms-sample.html

http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.0a1/experiments/api-viewer/docs/jQuery.post/index.html

ASP.NET Example
 [Simple Form Submit in Jquery Mobile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15244084/simple-form-submit-in-jquery-mobile)

Comment: Thanks for your insight on this, will help me get started.  So, which would you suggest will work this best - to start with an html or aspx page?  It seems that most of the examples start with html.

Comment: i think you can start an html . in my past experience. use aspx page with CSS. some .net control will not display right style .  : )

Comment: Your advice is much appreciated.