# jQuery Mobile data retrieval

Tags: jquery, json, jquery-mobile, jquery-plugins, rss

What is the best way to retrieve  data from multiple websites/pages and put them on 1 single application that gets auto-updated?
say ,I want to take an article from yahoo, and another one from bbc and another one from the times then put them on a sort of listview, that gets autoUpdated, how would I go for that?
I heard about JSON, but Since I'm new in jQuery Mobile programming, I'm not sure how this will work. Do I have to first, implement JSON on the websites I wanna take the article from, then use a JSON call from my App?or is there another way of doing this?
Thanks for your advice in advance.

Regards,
Ben

Comment: jQuery will run on clients. To get data from several sites, you'll end up facing [cross-domain issues](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing). The simplest way is to build a **server-side** web application that (1) will gather info from all those sites; (2) enrich them as you need and (3) serve them (in JSON format, probably) in the same domain as your jQuery-html page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not that hard.

There's no point in doing anything by yourself. Every major news site has a RSS feed. All you need is a jQuery RSS reader that can be used for article pulling. They can be than appended to the jQuery Mobile listview.

Here's one great jQuery RSS plugin: https://github.com/sdepold/jquery-rss

What to do:

1. Create skeleton jQuery Mobile page
2. Use RSS plugin to retrieve at least 10-30 articles
3. Store articles in **[localStorage](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp)**
4. Display them in a listview
5. Create another page
6. When user clicks on a listview element pass a article parameter to the second page. Read my other article to find out how you can pass parameters from page to page: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14469041/1848600
7. Before second page is loaded read rest of article data (from localStorage) and dynamically build page content. Read my other article how you can enhance markup of a dynamically created jQuery Mobile page: [jQuery Mobile: Markup Enhancement of dynamically added content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14550396/jquery-mobile-markup-enhancement-of-dynamically-added-content/14550417#14550417)

Comment: Thanks very much for the prompt answer.
If it's not a news site, but a private site, how would I go on doing, in the event that that private site does not use RSS feed?
Thanks

Comment: If that private side is yours you can do it like this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15205612/1848600 with json. You can even use other sites if they would allow you to access them, again with json.