# Ajax Post Error Loading Page

Tags: php, ajax, jquery-mobile

I have a form in which Ajax is used to send data to a php file.
THE DATA SENDS PROPERLY...EVERYTHING WORKS FINE...
BUT an "Error loading page" message pops up (using jquerymobile)

html file

```
<div data-role="page" id="cc">
<div data-role="header">
    <h1>Home</h1>
</div>
<div data-role="content">
    <form id="cname" align="left" action="post">
        <label for="name">Name:</label>
        <input type="text" id="name" name="name" value=""  />
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" data-inline="true">
    </form>


    <div id="result" style="visibility: hidden"></div>
</div>
</div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
       $("#cname").submit(function (e) {
           e.preventDefault();
           $.ajax({
               url: 'http://www.clubbedin.isadcharity.org/createclub.php',
               crossDomain: true, //set as a cross domain requests
               type: 'post',
               data: $("#cname").serialize(),
               success: function (data) {
                   $("#result").html(data);
               },
           });
        });
    </script>
```

php file

```
header("access-control-allow-origin: *");

$name = $_POST['name'];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your form must also have have this attribute:

```
data-ajax="false"
```

Without it jQuery Mobile will initialize its own ajax logic for form posting and you don't want that. Read more about it [**here**](http://blog.linuxacademy.com/jquery-mobile/tip-disable-ajax-on-jquery-mobile-forms/) or read my other **[answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15205437/jquery-mobile-how-to-correctly-submit-form-data/15205612#15205612)** on how to properly handle forms in jQuery Mobile.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this in your JavaScript:

```
jQuery.support.cors = true;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding

```
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, OPTIONS
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type, *
```

to your header