# jquery mobile remove ajax call from input button

Tags: jquery, forms, jquery-mobile, button, submit

using jquery mobile i would like to disable the ajax call for `input type Button`.

i know how to disable ajax call with normal link using following method data-ajax="false", but it will not work for me when i tried for form submit button. i just want disable ajax call for my form submit button.

this is my content:

```
<form action="<?php echo $action; ?>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="text" name="firstname" value="" placeholder="* Firstname" />
<input type="text" name="lastname" value="" placeholder="Last Name" />
 <input type="submit" value="<?php echo $button_continue; ?>" data-corners="false" data-theme="a" data-ajax="false" />
</form>
```

thanks for any help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just add an attribute **`data-ajax="false"`** to your form tag, like this:

```
<form id="check-user" class="ui-body ui-body-a ui-corner-all" data-ajax="false">

</form>
```

And [**here's**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15205437/jquery-mobile-how-to-correctly-submit-form-data/15205612#15205612) an example in my other answer.

Also read more about it in an official **[documentation](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.1/docs/forms/forms-sample.html)**.