# Correct way to submit a phonegap/jQM form.

Tags: forms, jquery-mobile, cordova

very new at this. Could someone tell me what is the best method of submitting a form when using phonegap and JMQ?  What I want to be able to do is passing the form data to a php file and then having the results passed back into app so that the user isnt directly accessing the php file at any point.

I found the following page [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15205437/jquery-mobile-how-to-correctly-submit-form-data/) which basically does what I want but I keep getting "Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin" when testing out the code. So I'm guessing this will only work if the app is located on a server also?

Any happy would be great. thank <3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To test your solution on the computer you need to launch chrome from the terminal with the argument `--disable-web-security`. See this answer: [Disable same origin policy in Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3102819/chrome-disable-same-origin-policy)

In your Phonegap application you add a line of code to your config.xml in the www-folder: `<access origin="*.yourdomain.com" />`. Build, and you are now allowed to request all domains and subdomains from yourdomain.com. For more details on whitelisting see http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.0.0/guide_appdev_whitelist_index.md.html#Domain%20Whitelist%20Guide

Answer (score 1):

You are not able to make post through the local files, so Yes, you need to have it running in a Web Server.

But if you deploy your application, it should work either in a emulator or in your device.